# Homogenous Poisson process

Tags: stochastic-processes

Consider a homogeneous Poisson process $N$ with rate $\lambda$. For For $0 < s < t$, I'm trying to show that:

$$P(N_t-N_s=0\mid N_t>0)= \frac{e^{\lambda s} - 1}{e^{\lambda t} - 1}$$

I'm mainly thinking of using some sort of conditioning and/or rewriting the expression

Comment: I reformatted the math, check if it's ok.

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
P(N_t-N_s=0 \mid N_t>0) = \frac{P(N_t-N_s=0\  \&\  N_t>0)}{P(N_t>0)} = \frac{P(N_t-N_s=0\  \&\  N_s>0)}{P(N_t>0)}.
$$
**First** figure out what the above is true.  Think about what it means.

Then exploit the fact that the two events with "$\&$" between them are independent.  Make sure you understand why they're independent.

**Later note in response to comments below:**
What was done above was for the purpose of writing the expression in terms of events that are **independent**. 
$$
\Pr(N_t-N_s=0) = e^{-(t-s)\lambda}
$$
$$
\Pr(N_s>0) = 1 - e^{-s\lambda}
$$
$$
\Pr(N_t>0) = 1 - e^{-t\lambda}
$$
So we have
$$
\frac{e^{-(t-s)\lambda}(1 - e^{-s\lambda})}{1 - e^{-t\lambda}}.
$$
Multiplying out the numerator, we get:
$$
\frac{e^{-(t-s)\lambda} - e^{-t\lambda}}{1 - e^{-t\lambda}}.
$$
Then multiply both the numerator and the denominator by $e^{t\lambda}$, and we get:
$$
\frac{e^{s\lambda}-1}{e^{t\lambda}-1}.
$$

Comment: So when independent I can say, P(nt- ns) * P(Ns)/P(Nt>0) but what cancells?

Comment: You have to work out the three probabilities first and _then_ worry about what cancels, if anything.  At some points you might want to multiply a numerator and denominator by $e^{s\lambda}$ or $e^{t\lambda}$, thereby changing $1-e^{-s\lambda}$ to $e^{s\lambda}-1$, etc.

Comment: I'm not following the three probabilities. Can you elaborate please and provide details? Thx

Comment: I added some more details above.

Answer (score 0):

Because $0<s<t$ and the probability is conditioned on $t$ instead of $s$, I would use Bayes' rule so that the two condition becomes reversed. That is,

$$P(N_t-N_s=0\mid N_t>0)= \frac{P(N_t-N_s=0)}{P(N_t>0)}P(N_t>0|N_t=N_s) = \frac{P(N_t-N_s=0)}{P(N_t>0)}P(N_s>0)$$

Then you should get it after some algebra.

Comment: I don't realy follow your argument, can you please elaborate on it

Comment: Intuitively, I want the condition to be based on past, not future. So I apply Bayes' rule in the first equality. The second equality is just simplifying the second term.